# how can I get Stripe charge id from a Shopify webhook if I am using Shopify with direct Stripe integration (not zdhopify payments)?

Tags: shopify, stripe-payments

I investigated Shopify api, and I am not able to find the following information:
id that I can use to obtain the CC charge from Stripe.

We are trying to use Stripe for backorder situations, so after credit card has been authorized on Stripe via Shopify, we would like to have a Stripe charge id so that we can charge it later via Stripe directly. We are using direct integration with Stripe via payment gateway (not Shopify payments).

Is possible to get the Stripe charge id after Shopify has sent a request to Stripe while authorizing the card?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, there is no chance of an ID like that... if you sense otherwise, great!

```
payment_details
{ "avs_result_code" : "null" }
{ "credit_card_bin" : "null" }
{ "cvv_result_code" : "null" }
{ "credit_card_number" : "•••• •••• •••• 4242" }
{ "credit_card_company" : "Visa" }
An object containing information about the payment. It has the following properties:

avs_result_code: The Response code from AVS the address verification system. The code is a single letter; see this chart for the codes and their definitions.
credit_card_bin: The issuer identification number (IIN), formerly known as bank identification number (BIN) ] of the customer's credit card. This is made up of the first few digits of the credit card number.
credit_card_company: The name of the company who issued the customer's credit card.
credit_card_number: The customer's credit card number, with most of the leading digits redacted with Xs.
cvv_result_code: The Response code from the credit card company indicating whether the customer entered the card security code, a.k.a. card verification value, correctly. The code is a single letter or empty string; see this chart for the codes and their definitions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Transaction](http://docs.shopify.com/api/transaction) contains what you're looking for?

From the Shopify API docs:

> #### Transaction Properties
>
> **authorization**
>   The authorization code associated with the transaction.
>
> **gateway**
>   The name of the gateway the transaction was issued through.
>
> **id**
>   A unique numeric identifier for the transaction.
>
> **kind**
>   The kind of transaction: authorization, capture, sale, void, refund